# Как получить поля и значения полей из Json ответа?

Tags: android, json, android-studio

Вот такой ответ json

```
{
  "result": {
    "stats": [
      {
        "balance": "0.00000000",
        "rejected_speed": "0.00000000",
        "algo": 0,
        "accepted_speed": "0.00000000"
      },
      {
        "balance": "0.00000017",
        "rejected_speed": "0.00000000",
        "algo": 8,
        "accepted_speed": "0.00000000"
      },
      {
        "balance": "0.00000387",
        "rejected_speed": "0.00000000",
        "algo": 14,
        "accepted_speed": "0.00000000"
      },
      {
        "balance": "0.00000919",
        "rejected_speed": "0.00000000",
        "algo": 20,
        "accepted_speed": "0.00000000"
      },
      {
        "balance": "0.00000039",
        "rejected_speed": "0.00000000",
        "algo": 21,
        "accepted_speed": "0.00000000"
      },
      {
        "balance": "0.00109017",
        "rejected_speed": "0.00000000",
        "algo": 22,
        "accepted_speed": "0.00000000"
      },
      {
        "balance": "0.00001072",
        "rejected_speed": "0.00000000",
        "algo": 23,
        "accepted_speed": "0.00000000"
      },
      {
        "balance": "0.00232138",
        "rejected_speed": "0.00000000",
        "algo": 24,
        "accepted_speed": "0.00000018"
      },
      {
        "balance": "0.00000063",
        "rejected_speed": "0.00000000",
        "algo": 25,
        "accepted_speed": "0.00000000"
      },
      {
        "balance": "0.00000051",
        "rejected_speed": "0.00000000",
        "algo": 26,
        "accepted_speed": "0.00000000"
      }
    ],
    "payments": [
      {
        "amount": "0.01075006",
        "fee": "0.00044792",
        "TXID": "95137a6e168ca93b9c0d408713bb241f5fa8985f9d5647c58528694f1029b0d5",
        "time": "2017-06-27 09:59:35"
      }
    ],
    "addr": "18vR1WduiURoKwQ6YdxGhcRMr3pcaKxJhv"
  },
  "method": "stats.provider"
}
```

1. Нужно вытащить все цифровые значения , и вывести допустим в `textview`
2. Есть ли тут `JSONArray` вообще?

Comment: да, это json. В чем именно у вас проблема? Библиотек для разбора JSON вагон и маленькая тележка

Comment: Да, есть массив

Comment: А без библиотек чтобы, стандартным JSONObject можно?

Comment: стандартный JSONObject и есть библиотека.

Comment: @rjhdby, дело в том что я не понимаю где здесь начало массива и конец, и тут их по моему два. Подкиньте примерчик хотя бы 1.

Comment: @Сергей, сначала скажи, ты получил эту строку в приложение?Или само получение тоже нужно сделать?

Comment: @zayn1991, получение есть, в логи json выскакивает

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://json2java.azurewebsites.net

Это сайт для создания модели класса данных. Копируешь свой массив json и сайт отдаст готовые поля. А саму строку вроде передаешь в объект

```
ArrayList <ClassItem> arrayList = new ArrayList <>();
// массив для заполнения
JSONObject  object = new JSONObject(stroka) ;
// тут создали общий объект Json из строки, полученной из интернета
JSONObject result = object.getJsonObject ("result") ;
// тут вытаскиваем из объекта другой объект, чей ключ  равен "result"
JSONArray statsArray = result.getJsonArray ("stats") ;
Тут достали массив объектов по ключу "stats"
for(int i =0;i <statsArray.lenth (); i++){
    ClassItem item = new ClassItem ();
    item.balance = statsArray.get (i).optString ("balance");
    // остальные поля заполняешь так же. 
    // в примере написал optString; там есть и optInt() и так далее. 
}
arrayList.add (item);

JSONArray payments = result.getJsonArray ("payments") ;
Тут достали массив объектов по ключу "payments"
for(int i =0;i <payments.lenth (); i++){
    ClassItemForPayments item2 = new ClassItemForPayments ();
    item2.znachenie= payments.get (i).optString ("amount");
    // остальные поля заполняешь так же. 
    // в примере написал optString; там есть и optInt() и так далее. 
}
arrayListForPayments.add (item);

String address = result.optString ("addr");
String method = object.optStrin("method");
```

Код написал через телефон и где то мог ошибиться. Поправьте, если где то ошибся, но суть понятна,  думаю. Задавай вопросы в комменте, постараюсь ответить

Comment: Погодика, это же все в цикле правильно?

Comment: @Сергей, в цикле только то, что у тебя в строке в квадратных скобках [ ] . Заметьте, что у вас поле "algo" имеет значение не в кавычках, а остальные в кавычках " " , это означает, что значение в кавычках должно приниматься, как строка, а без кавычек значение числового типа

Comment: @Сергей я дописал реализацию. Посмотри примерно иерархию, откуда я что вытаскивал и как доставать, тебе станет понятнее. Дебаг тебе с логами сильно помогут

Comment: Ты не шаришь? Можно автоматически десериализовать JSON в Java объект с помощью [GSON](https://dzone.com/articles/deserializing-json-java-object) или [Jackson](https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-convert-java-object-to-from-json-jackson/)

Comment: @Alex78191, я показал, как можно ручками. Мой ответ не правильный, что идёт без подключения либ? Или тебя задело, что я либу в ответе не расписал ? Я не понимаю тебя. Человек может быть новичком и ему надо показывать азы и как это работает. Напиши тогда о либах вторым ответом

Comment: @zayn1991, спасибо за подробное объяснение, я попробую.

Comment: @Сергей указал как можно конвертировать автоматически https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/686878/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d0%b8-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%b9-%d0%b8%d0%b7-json-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%b0/686890?noredirect=1#comment1012065_686890

Comment: @Alex78191, он как раз шарит. Тащить ли в проект зависимости чтобы разобрать простецкий JSON, каждый решает сам.